# Django error 'URLs with hostname components are not permitted'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have deployed a django application which invokes a python file to send captured data on django form to a third party independent server. The problem is that when the python file is invoked from django form, it leads to this error as seen on the browser -

```
file: URLs with hostname components are not permitted

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/phone_associate_form/
Django Version:     3.1.3
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

file: URLs with hostname components are not permitted

Exception Location:     E:\INVOKEDID\lib\site-packages\requests_file.py, line 34, in send
```

Here is the output for local variables as seen

```
kwargs  

{'cert': None,
 'proxies': OrderedDict(),
 'stream': False,
 'timeout': 20,
 'verify': False}

request     

<PreparedRequest [GET]>

self    

<requests_file.FileAdapter object at 0x000001DBB1302B88>

url_parts   

ParseResult(scheme='file', netloc='E:', path='/INVOKEDID/NumberRepo/MASTERHANDLER/axlsqltoolkit/schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Here is pip freeze output from django -

```
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.3.0
attrs==20.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20200713
Django==3.1.3
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
django-easy-audit==1.3.0
django-import-export==2.4.0
django-shibboleth-remoteuser==0.12
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
idna==2.10
isodate==0.6.0
jdcal==1.4.1
lxml==4.6.1
MarkupPy==1.14
numpy==1.19.4
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.5
pandas==1.1.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-file==1.5.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
tablib==2.0.0
urllib3==1.25.11
xlrd==1.2.0
xlwt==1.3.0
zeep==4.0.0
```

```
Here is the view-

def phone_associate_form(request, id=0):
    if request.method =="POST":
        if id==0:
            print ('in post block of view')
            form = Phone_MAC_Address_Model_Form(request.POST)
            print ('get mac address from page')
            phone_mac_address = request.POST.get('phone_mac_address')
            country = request.POST.get('country_id')
            print(country)
            return_result=phone_mac_acd_associate_custom(phone_mac_address)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return redirect('phone_associate_list')
```

Here is the url-

```
path('phone_associate_form/', views.phone_associate_form, name='phone_associate_form'),
path('phone_associate_list/', views.phone_associate_list, name='phone_associate_list'),
```

Comment: can you please attach the urls.py and the view's code?
also reformat the text in the question

Comment: here is the urls.py section -

`
    path('phone_associate_form/', views.phone_associate_form, name='phone_associate_form'),
    path('phone_associate_list/', views.phone_associate_list, name='phone_associate_list'),

`

Views section below -
`

`

Comment: I think at this point would be better if you post the view's code

Comment: here is the view code -


def phone_associate_form(request, id=0):
 if request.method =="POST":
  if id==0:
   print ('in post block of view')
   form = Phone_MAC_Address_Model_Form(request.POST)
   print ('get mac address from page')
   phone_mac_address = request.POST.get('phone_mac_address')
   country = request.POST.get('country_id')
   print(country)
   return_result=phone_mac_acd_associate_custom(phone_mac_address)
   if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
   return redirect('phone_associate_list')

Comment: can you add that code to the question? in a comment is not readable. If you can't I can edit the original post for you

Comment: @MassimoCosta, edited the post with formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with zeep 4.0.0.
For now, try a 'pip install zeep==3.4.0'